# React-leaflet giving window undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet and server-side react to draw a map. I created a map component and also tried using the `useEffect` hook to dynamically load the import to bypass this error:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

This is the code I have:

```
import React, {  
    useEffect,
    useState,
} from 'react';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

const MyMapComponent = () => {

    const [leafletLoaded, setLeafletLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadData = async () => {
            await import('leaflet/dist/leaflet.js');
                setLeafletLoaded(true);
        }
        loadData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
                <Popup>
                    A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        </MapContainer> 
    );
};


export default MyMapComponent;
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Do you have Server side rendering?

Comment: Yes it's SSR react

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect is not necessary, the code works for me without:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const loadData = async () => {
            await import('leaflet/dist/leaflet.js');
                setLeafletLoaded(true);
        }
        loadData();
    }, []);
```

Check versions react and install leaflet:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"react-leaflet": "^3.2.1",
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this is server-side rendering react

Comment: any update on the issue